# Javascript : Change button text according to hidden variable value

Tags: javascript

i have hidden variable with default value "on" , i want to change the text of another button from Disable to Enable according to this hidden value , if the hidden field value is "on" the button text is "Disable" and vice verse . i have tried but my solution doesn't work

hidden field

```
 <input  name="hiddenV"  type="hidden"  id="hiddenValue<%=ud.getUserId()%>" value="on" />
```

button

```
 <input   type="button"  id="delUserButton<%=ud.getUserId()%>" onclick="openDelDiv(<%=ud.getUserId()%>, '<%=ud.getUserName()%>'); change(this.id);" value="Disable"/>
```

js function

```
function change(btn) {

                var hiddenValue = document.getElementsByName("hiddenV")[0];
                var disButton = document.getElementById(btn);
                if (hiddenValue.value === "on")
                    disButton.value = "Disable";
                else
                    disButton.value = "Enable";
            }
```

OpendelDev() : it's a popup dialog like  ( are you sure you want to disable this user) with ok button that causes the page to reload

```
 function openDelDiv(userId, userName) {

                $("#userId_delete").val(userId);
                $("#userName_delete").text(userName);
                $("#delUserDiv").bPopup();

            }
```

but put in mind that the button is placed in for loop inside a jsp page so the id for every button will be different

Comment: Your code looks good, what's your problem ?

Comment: the button text doesn't change after i clicked the button and the page reloaded :((

Comment: And are you sure that your hidden field value is changed? Maybe it stays to "on" (hence no button text change). Note that it feels like you're faking a `checkbox` or `radio` button here.

Comment: @Xenos any suggestion to solve this issue ?

Comment: Your code is fine!

Comment: nothing changes because hidden field  value="on" so the button text will remain "Disable", change the value(e.g value="off") and the button text will change.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are actually faking a `<input type="radio"/>` here.

The goal is then to have an input for each possible value, along with a list of buttons to toggle them. Then, all you have to do is show the buttons you want (ie: show "enable" button if status "disabled" is checked and vice-versa).

```
<input type="radio" class="input-field" name="status" value="enabled" checked="checked" id="a"/>
<input type="radio" class="input-field" name="status" value="disabled" id="b"/>
<ul class="buttons">
    <li>
        <label class="enabling" for="a">
            <button>Enable</span>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label class="disabling" for="b">
            <span>Disable</span>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In CSS:

```
.input-field[value="enabled"]:checked ~ ul.buttons label.enabling,
.input-field[value="disabled"]:checked ~ ul.buttons label.disabling {
    display: none;
}
```

(not actually run & tested, but the spirit is there)